# Unable to instantiate application when it obviously exists

Tags: android

Since I've started developing an application I haven't received any "Unable to instantiate application" exceptions , however, after the launch there've been quite a number of bug-reports that stated this exception.

My application uses custom MyApplication class inherited from Application, manifest's record looks like `.application.MyApplication` and I still can't reproduce the same exception neither on 2.3 nor on 4.0. Can you suggest what might be happening there ?

**UPD**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to obtain the stack dump from when the exception happened? Please post it here since it might provide more information.

Comment: I've posted - any suggestions ? I actually noticed this bug once or twice on ICS, don't know how to mend it though.

Comment: If this is only happening occasionally and runs fine at other times, I have no idea. If it happens all the time for a certain user, it is likely due to a bad/corrupted APK.